# Difference between buildpack and droplet

Tags: cloud-foundry, buildpack

Here is my understanding of cloudfoundry buildpacks and droplets

**buildpack** is runtimes(say, jdk) + containers(say, tomcat) + frameworks(say, spring) + service configs (if any) + your apps (if any).

**droplet** is buildpack deployed on a linux container.

Please correct or add additional information.

Comment: it looks like the answer is accurate. You may want to accept it.

Comment: i wanted someone to second it. thanks

Comment: Well then, how about a little love for my comment with an up arrow!? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A **buildpack** is a collection of three binaries: *detect*, *compile*, and *release*.  When your app bits are pushed to Cloud Foundry, the *detect* from all the available buildpacks are run against your bits until one returns `true`.  For example, the Ruby buildpack checks to see if there's a `Gemfile`, the Python buildpack looks for a `requirements.txt`, etc.  Next, the *compile* phase turns your app bits into a single runnable package, which means compiling the code (if necessary) and bundling in any additional things needed, such as JDK, tomcat, spring, etc; or a Ruby interpreter, gems, etc.  That single executable is the **droplet**.  Finally, the *release* phase presents the droplet and associated metadata so that the stager can upload them to the cloud controller.

To run your app, the droplet is retrieved from the cloud controller and run inside a container.

Basically, a buildpack packages your app into a droplet, which consists of your app + some other stuff, or a compiled binary version of your app, and the droplet is then run in a container.

Answer (score 0):

**Buildpacks** are scripts which provides run time support for your Application. A build pack is a script which which contains instructions to detect, supply, finalize and release. They essentially   provides your application runtime + app framework + related dependency.

**Droplet** is tarball file which contains Your APP+run time + framework+ dependency . This package is out put of staging and is finally deployed.